# Program too slow, Need to optimize the inverse calculus

Tags: matlab

Consider the following code :

```
T01 = [cos(t1) -sin(t1)*cos(alpha1) sin(alpha1)*sin(t1) a1*cos(t1);sin(t1) cos(t1)*cos(alpha1) -cos(alpha1)*sin(t1) a1*sin(t1);0 sin(alpha1) cos(alpha1) d1 ;0 0 0 1];
T12 = [cos(t2) -sin(t2)*cos(alpha2) sin(alpha2)*sin(t2) a2*cos(t2);sin(t2) cos(t2)*cos(alpha2) -cos(alpha2)*sin(t2) a2*sin(t2);0 sin(alpha2) cos(alpha2) d2 ;0 0 0 1];
T23 = [cos(t3) -sin(t3)*cos(alpha3) sin(alpha3)*sin(t3) a3*cos(t3);sin(t3) cos(t3)*cos(alpha3) -cos(alpha3)*sin(t3) a3*sin(t3);0 sin(alpha3) cos(alpha3) d3 ;0 0 0 1];
T34 = [cos(t4) -sin(t4)*cos(alpha4) sin(alpha4)*sin(t4) a4*cos(t4);sin(t4) cos(t4)*cos(alpha4) -cos(alpha4)*sin(t4) a4*sin(t4);0 sin(alpha4) cos(alpha4) d4 ;0 0 0 1];
T45 = [cos(t5) -sin(t5)*cos(alpha5) sin(alpha5)*sin(t5) a5*cos(t5);sin(t5) cos(t5)*cos(alpha5) -cos(alpha5)*sin(t5) a5*sin(t5);0 sin(alpha5) cos(alpha5) d5 ;0 0 0 1];
T56 = [cos(t6) -sin(t6)*cos(alpha6) sin(alpha6)*sin(t6) a6*cos(t6);sin(t6) cos(t6)*cos(alpha6) -cos(alpha6)*sin(t6) a6*sin(t6);0 sin(alpha6) cos(alpha6) d6 ;0 0 0 1];

T= T01*T12*T23*T34*T45*T56 ;

vect = [T(1,4);T(2,4);T(3,4)];
tet= [t1;t2;t3;t4;t5;t6];

J=jacobian(vect,tet);

XYZinit=[x;y;z];
H=pinv(J);

qCible=(tet+(H*(vect-XYZinit)))*180.0/pi;
```

In this case the program takes too long calculating the qCible.
I had a look on the Jacobian and it was very complex having "4967757600021511/405648192073033408478945025720320" and more !

Is there any way to make Matlab simplify these numbers to 3 digits after the decimal point.

P.S this is for exemple the 2nd line of the Jacobian matrix:

```
[ (667495948725283505644223413159337121101697927362615132085977267803570842210039392837475731450497*cos(t1))/66749594872528440074844428317798503581334516323645399060845050244444366430645017188217565216768000 + (180182749026672061615969125490030497260998891573948681728240766153*cos(t1)*sin(t2))/822752278660603021077484591278675252491367932816789931674304512000 + (23859816081157487611247053147082199287638984338758594710122908873*sin(t3)*(cos(t1) + (4967757600021511*cos(t1)*sin(t2))/81129638414606681695789005144064 + (4967757600021511*cos(t2)*sin(t1))/81129638414606681695789005144064))/822752278660603021077484591278675252491367932816789931674304512000 + (895104220870018647914711647235873838858522473234640872822096410779044699920717183*sin(t1)*sin(t2))/66749594872528440074844428317798503581334516323645399060845050244444366430645017188217565216768000 - (4967757600021511*sin(t5)*(cos(t1)*sin(t2) - (4967757600021511*cos(t1))/81129638414606681695789005144064 + sin(t3)*(cos(t1) + (4967757600021511*cos(t1)*sin(t2))/81129638414606681695789005144064 + (4967757600021511*cos(t2)*sin(t1))/81129638414606681695789005144064) + (4967757600021511*sin(t1)*sin(t2))/81129638414606681695789005144064 - (4967757600021511*cos(t4)*(cos(t3)*(cos(t1) + (4967757600021511*cos(t1)*sin(t2))/81129638414606681695789005144064 + (4967757600021511*cos(t2)*sin(t1))/81129638414606681695789005144064) + sin(t3)*(cos(t1)*cos(t2) - sin(t1)*sin(t2))))/81129638414606681695789005144064 + (4967757600021511*sin(t4)*(sin(t3)*(cos(t1) + (4967757600021511*cos(t1)*sin(t2))/81129638414606681695789005144064 + (4967757600021511*cos(t2)*sin(t1))/81129638414606681695789005144064) - cos(t3)*(cos(t1)*cos(t2) - sin(t1)*sin(t2))))/81129638414606681695789005144064))/405648192073033408478945025720320 - (21*cos(t4)*(sin(t3)*(cos(t1) + (4967757600021511*cos(t1)*sin(t2))/81129638414606681695789005144064 + (4967757600021511*cos(t2)*sin(t1))/81129638414606681695789005144064) - cos(t3)*(cos(t1)*cos(t2) - sin(t1)*sin(t2))))/1000 - (17277797851872663442627176416851563336929412302080901873592316727*sin(t4)*(cos(t3)*(cos(t1) + (4967757600021511*cos(t1)*sin(t2))/81129638414606681695789005144064 + (4967757600021511*cos(t2)*sin(t1))/81129638414606681695789005144064) + sin(t3)*(cos(t1)*cos(t2) - sin(t1)*sin(t2))))/822752278660603021077484591278675252491367932816789931674304512000 - (4967757600021511*sin(t4)*(sin(t3)*(cos(t1) + (4967757600021511*cos(t1)*sin(t2))/81129638414606681695789005144064 + (4967757600021511*cos(t2)*sin(t1))/81129638414606681695789005144064) - cos(t3)*(cos(t1)*cos(t2) - sin(t1)*sin(t2))))/405648192073033408478945025720320 + (sin(t5)*(cos(t4)*(sin(t3)*(cos(t1) + (4967757600021511*cos(t1)*sin(t2))/81129638414606681695789005144064 + (4967757600021511*cos(t2)*sin(t1))/81129638414606681695789005144064) - cos(t3)*(cos(t1)*cos(t2) - sin(t1)*sin(t2))) + sin(t4)*(cos(t3)*(cos(t1) + (4967757600021511*cos(t1)*sin(t2))/81129638414606681695789005144064 + (4967757600021511*cos(t2)*sin(t1))/81129638414606681695789005144064) + sin(t3)*(cos(t1)*cos(t2) - sin(t1)*sin(t2)))))/5 + (19*cos(t3)*(cos(t1)*cos(t2) - sin(t1)*sin(t2)))/100, (sin(t5)*(cos(t4)*(sin(t3)*((4967757600021511*cos(t1)*sin(t2))/81129638414606681695789005144064 + (4967757600021511*cos(t2)*sin(t1))/81129638414606681695789005144064) - cos(t3)*(cos(t1)*cos(t2) - sin(t1)*sin(t2))) + sin(t4)*(cos(t3)*((4967757600021511*cos(t1)*sin(t2))/81129638414606681695789005144064 + (4967757600021511*cos(t2)*sin(t1))/81129638414606681695789005144064) + sin(t3)*(cos(t1)*cos(t2) - sin(t1)*sin(t2)))))/5 - (895104220870018647914711647235873838858522473234640872822096410779044699920717183*cos(t1)*cos(t2))/66749594872528440074844428317798503581334516323645399060845050244444366430645017188217565216768000 + (180182749026672061615969125490030497260998891573948681728240766153*cos(t2)*sin(t1))/822752278660603021077484591278675252491367932816789931674304512000 - (4967757600021511*sin(t5)*(cos(t2)*sin(t1) - (4967757600021511*cos(t1)*cos(t2))/81129638414606681695789005144064 + sin(t3)*((4967757600021511*cos(t1)*sin(t2))/81129638414606681695789005144064 + (4967757600021511*cos(t2)*sin(t1))/81129638414606681695789005144064) - (4967757600021511*cos(t4)*(cos(t3)*((4967757600021511*cos(t1)*sin(t2))/81129638414606681695789005144064 + (4967757600021511*cos(t2)*sin(t1))/81129638414606681695789005144064) + sin(t3)*(cos(t1)*cos(t2) - sin(t1)*sin(t2))))/81129638414606681695789005144064 + (4967757600021511*sin(t4)*(sin(t3)*((4967757600021511*cos(t1)*sin(t2))/81129638414606681695789005144064 + (4967757600021511*cos(t2)*sin(t1))/81129638414606681695789005144064) - cos(t3)*(cos(t1)*cos(t2) - sin(t1)*sin(t2))))/81129638414606681695789005144064))/405648192073033408478945025720320 + (23859816081157487611247053147082199287638984338758594710122908873*sin(t3)*((4967757600021511*cos(t1)*sin(t2))/81129638414606681695789005144064 + (4967757600021511*cos(t2)*sin(t1))/81129638414606681695789005144064))/822752278660603021077484591278675252491367932816789931674304512000 - (21*cos(t4)*(sin(t3)*((4967757600021511*cos(t1)*sin(t2))/81129638414606681695789005144064 + (4967757600021511*cos(t2)*sin(t1))/81129638414606681695789005144064) - cos(t3)*(cos(t1)*cos(t2) - sin(t1)*sin(t2))))/1000 - (17277797851872663442627176416851563336929412302080901873592316727*sin(t4)*(cos(t3)*((4967757600021511*cos(t1)*sin(t2))/81129638414606681695789005144064 + (4967757600021511*cos(t2)*sin(t1))/81129638414606681695789005144064) + sin(t3)*(cos(t1)*cos(t2) - sin(t1)*sin(t2))))/822752278660603021077484591278675252491367932816789931674304512000 - (4967757600021511*sin(t4)*(sin(t3)*((4967757600021511*cos(t1)*sin(t2))/81129638414606681695789005144064 + (4967757600021511*cos(t2)*sin(t1))/81129638414606681695789005144064) - cos(t3)*(cos(t1)*cos(t2) - sin(t1)*sin(t2))))/405648192073033408478945025720320 + (19*cos(t3)*(cos(t1)*cos(t2) - sin(t1)*sin(t2)))/100, (23859816081157487611247053147082199287638984338758594710122908873*cos(t3)*(sin(t1) - (4967757600021511*cos(t1)*cos(t2))/81129638414606681695789005144064 + (4967757600021511*sin(t1)*sin(t2))/81129638414606681695789005144064))/822752278660603021077484591278675252491367932816789931674304512000 - (4967757600021511*sin(t5)*(cos(t3)*(sin(t1) - (4967757600021511*cos(t1)*cos(t2))/81129638414606681695789005144064 + (4967757600021511*sin(t1)*sin(t2))/81129638414606681695789005144064) + (4967757600021511*cos(t4)*(sin(t3)*(sin(t1) - (4967757600021511*cos(t1)*cos(t2))/81129638414606681695789005144064 + (4967757600021511*sin(t1)*sin(t2))/81129638414606681695789005144064) - cos(t3)*(cos(t1)*sin(t2) + cos(t2)*sin(t1))))/81129638414606681695789005144064 + (4967757600021511*sin(t4)*(cos(t3)*(sin(t1) - (4967757600021511*cos(t1)*cos(t2))/81129638414606681695789005144064 + (4967757600021511*sin(t1)*sin(t2))/81129638414606681695789005144064) + sin(t3)*(cos(t1)*sin(t2) + cos(t2)*sin(t1))))/81129638414606681695789005144064))/405648192073033408478945025720320 - (21*cos(t4)*(cos(t3)*(sin(t1) - (4967757600021511*cos(t1)*cos(t2))/81129638414606681695789005144064 + (4967757600021511*sin(t1)*sin(t2))/81129638414606681695789005144064) + sin(t3)*(cos(t1)*sin(t2) + cos(t2)*sin(t1))))/1000 - (4967757600021511*sin(t4)*(cos(t3)*(sin(t1) - (4967757600021511*cos(t1)*cos(t2))/81129638414606681695789005144064 + (4967757600021511*sin(t1)*sin(t2))/81129638414606681695789005144064) + sin(t3)*(cos(t1)*sin(t2) + cos(t2)*sin(t1))))/405648192073033408478945025720320 + (17277797851872663442627176416851563336929412302080901873592316727*sin(t4)*(sin(t3)*(sin(t1) - (4967757600021511*cos(t1)*cos(t2))/81129638414606681695789005144064 + (4967757600021511*sin(t1)*sin(t2))/81129638414606681695789005144064) - cos(t3)*(cos(t1)*sin(t2) + cos(t2)*sin(t1))))/822752278660603021077484591278675252491367932816789931674304512000 - (19*sin(t3)*(cos(t1)*sin(t2) + cos(t2)*sin(t1)))/100 + (sin(t5)*(cos(t4)*(cos(t3)*(sin(t1) - (4967757600021511*cos(t1)*cos(t2))/81129638414606681695789005144064 + (4967757600021511*sin(t1)*sin(t2))/81129638414606681695789005144064) + sin(t3)*(cos(t1)*sin(t2) + cos(t2)*sin(t1))) - sin(t4)*(sin(t3)*(sin(t1) - (4967757600021511*cos(t1)*cos(t2))/81129638414606681695789005144064 + (4967757600021511*sin(t1)*sin(t2))/81129638414606681695789005144064) - cos(t3)*(cos(t1)*sin(t2) + cos(t2)*sin(t1)))))/5, (21*sin(t4)*(sin(t3)*(sin(t1) - (4967757600021511*cos(t1)*cos(t2))/81129638414606681695789005144064 + (4967757600021511*sin(t1)*sin(t2))/81129638414606681695789005144064) - cos(t3)*(cos(t1)*sin(t2) + cos(t2)*sin(t1))))/1000 - (17277797851872663442627176416851563336929412302080901873592316727*cos(t4)*(cos(t3)*(sin(t1) - (4967757600021511*cos(t1)*cos(t2))/81129638414606681695789005144064 + (4967757600021511*sin(t1)*sin(t2))/81129638414606681695789005144064) + sin(t3)*(cos(t1)*sin(t2) + cos(t2)*sin(t1))))/822752278660603021077484591278675252491367932816789931674304512000 - (4967757600021511*cos(t4)*(sin(t3)*(sin(t1) - (4967757600021511*cos(t1)*cos(t2))/81129638414606681695789005144064 + (4967757600021511*sin(t1)*sin(t2))/81129638414606681695789005144064) - cos(t3)*(cos(t1)*sin(t2) + cos(t2)*sin(t1))))/405648192073033408478945025720320 - (4967757600021511*sin(t5)*((4967757600021511*cos(t4)*(sin(t3)*(sin(t1) - (4967757600021511*cos(t1)*cos(t2))/81129638414606681695789005144064 + (4967757600021511*sin(t1)*sin(t2))/81129638414606681695789005144064) - cos(t3)*(cos(t1)*sin(t2) + cos(t2)*sin(t1))))/81129638414606681695789005144064 + (4967757600021511*sin(t4)*(cos(t3)*(sin(t1) - (4967757600021511*cos(t1)*cos(t2))/81129638414606681695789005144064 + (4967757600021511*sin(t1)*sin(t2))/81129638414606681695789005144064) + sin(t3)*(cos(t1)*sin(t2) + cos(t2)*sin(t1))))/81129638414606681695789005144064))/405648192073033408478945025720320 + (sin(t5)*(cos(t4)*(cos(t3)*(sin(t1) - (4967757600021511*cos(t1)*cos(t2))/81129638414606681695789005144064 + (4967757600021511*sin(t1)*sin(t2))/81129638414606681695789005144064) + sin(t3)*(cos(t1)*sin(t2) + cos(t2)*sin(t1))) - sin(t4)*(sin(t3)*(sin(t1) - (4967757600021511*cos(t1)*cos(t2))/81129638414606681695789005144064 + (4967757600021511*sin(t1)*sin(t2))/81129638414606681695789005144064) - cos(t3)*(cos(t1)*sin(t2) + cos(t2)*sin(t1)))))/5, (4967757600021511*cos(t5)*((4967757600021511*sin(t1))/81129638414606681695789005144064 + (4967757600021511*cos(t1)*sin(t2))/81129638414606681695789005144064 - sin(t1)*sin(t2) - sin(t3)*(sin(t1) - (4967757600021511*cos(t1)*cos(t2))/81129638414606681695789005144064 + (4967757600021511*sin(t1)*sin(t2))/81129638414606681695789005144064) + (4967757600021511*cos(t4)*(cos(t3)*(sin(t1) - (4967757600021511*cos(t1)*cos(t2))/81129638414606681695789005144064 + (4967757600021511*sin(t1)*sin(t2))/81129638414606681695789005144064) + sin(t3)*(cos(t1)*sin(t2) + cos(t2)*sin(t1))))/81129638414606681695789005144064 - (4967757600021511*sin(t4)*(sin(t3)*(sin(t1) - (4967757600021511*cos(t1)*cos(t2))/81129638414606681695789005144064 + (4967757600021511*sin(t1)*sin(t2))/81129638414606681695789005144064) - cos(t3)*(cos(t1)*sin(t2) + cos(t2)*sin(t1))))/81129638414606681695789005144064))/405648192073033408478945025720320 + (cos(t5)*(cos(t4)*(sin(t3)*(sin(t1) - (4967757600021511*cos(t1)*cos(t2))/81129638414606681695789005144064 + (4967757600021511*sin(t1)*sin(t2))/81129638414606681695789005144064) - cos(t3)*(cos(t1)*sin(t2) + cos(t2)*sin(t1))) + sin(t4)*(cos(t3)*(sin(t1) - (4967757600021511*cos(t1)*cos(t2))/81129638414606681695789005144064 + (4967757600021511*sin(t1)*sin(t2))/81129638414606681695789005144064) + sin(t3)*(cos(t1)*sin(t2) + cos(t2)*sin(t1)))))/5, 0]
```

Comment: Are you using symbolic math? Not sure if you're talking about the computation or about the display. In case it's the first, see https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/matlab/1141/performance-and-benchmarking/12687/its-ok-to-be-single#t=201707260959543504814

Comment: I'm sry I didn't mention that i'm using symbolic math
this didn't work with syms

Comment: Symbolic==slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the variable representation concern, using `double` to get a floating point view instead of rational. For example if `a = sym('4967757600021511/405648192073033408478945025720320');` you can make it double like `double(a)` which is shown like `1.2246e-17`.

## Update

As the question is updated by adding an example, you can do this in symbolic expressions using `vpa` similar to `double` for the previous part. For instance, if the name of the symbolic expression is `a` you can use `vpa(a, 3)`.

Comment: it's impossible to me make them double
I made a P.S to show you an exemple in the topic